# Two different URLs pointing to the same page

Tags: .htaccess, url-masking

Let say I have URL like http://www.example.com/pages/process-one.html, I want to add an entry in `.htaccess` that will let me visit the same page using the URL https://www.example.com/process/process-one.html - so people will use "process" instead of "pages".

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule /process/process-one.html /pages/process-one.html [L]`

You may need `RewriteBase /` or some other based on your server config. This htaccess goes in /.

Comment: Thank you for a fast reply, I'm using magento and I tried to apply the rewriterule but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have any other overriding rules? Most large PHP applications will consume everything, taking a route for /*

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default htaccess generated by Magento.